# Arrays and global variables

Tags: c

I'm trying to handle a global variable (matrix[]).

My first question is: What is an array with two indexes ([x][x]) called?
My second question is: In initialize(); I am trying to assign every element in matrix[] to a 'O', but it doesn't seem to work.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char matrix[4][10];

void initialize()
{
    matrix[4][10] = {{'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'},
                     {'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'},
                     {'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'},
                     {'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'}};

}

int main(void)
{

}
```

This code gives me the following error:

```
error: cannot convert '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'char' in assignment
```

Comment: First: Two dumensional array, or a matrix

Comment: To answer your first question: look at your variable name...

Comment: Your one and only statement in `initialize()` is an assignment to one element of the matrix. What about telling us what you want to do? I don't know programs that doesn't handle any data.

Comment: Why write a custom function? what's wrong with `memset(matrix[0], '0', sizeof(matrix));`? and so on?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's called 2 dimensional array.

You can use `= {...};` initialisation only in the same line where you declare an array. So

```
char matrix[4][10] = {{....}};
```

will work, but

```
char matrix[4][10];
matrix = {{...}};
```

will not.

You should use loops if you want to fill your array in some function:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        matrix[i][j] = 0;
```

And you left `main` function empty so `initialise` function will be never called.

Comment: @user2952320, if that worked for you, consider marking igoris' answer as accepted.

Answer (score 3):

No need for `initialize` here, just initialize the variable at the point of definition:

```
char matrix[4][10] = {{'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'},
                      {'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'},
                      {'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'},
                      {'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'}};
```

Comment: I have to initialize the positions in the array in the initialize() function. But I have to define the matrix array outside a function in order to make it global.

Answer (score 1):

1. call function `Initialize()` from main.
2. `matrix[4][10]` is a single character. you can't initialize as like what you did in your function.

Either do it by using loop and `memset()`
or 
Use two loops.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code to initialize variable size matrix `M x N` at runtime,

```
int **Create(int M , int N) // `M` & `N` are dimensions of the matrix 
{
    int **a, i, j;
    a = (int **)malloc(M * sizeof(int *));   // Create array of pointers

    for (i = 0; i <= M-1; i++) // Create `M` rows, there addresses are stored in array
         a[i] = (int *)malloc(N * sizeof(int));
    return a; // return address of the matrix
 }
```

Once matrix is created we can initialize the elements as below,

```
for(i = 0; i <= row - 1; i++)
  for(j = 0; j <= col - 1; j++)
     scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);   // Read a[i][j]
```